# moses crashed with segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, xml-rpc, moses

I am using Arch linux with next packages:

- gcc-multilib 4.8.2-4
- boost 1.54.0-4
- xmlrpc-c 1:1.36.00-1
- giza-pp 1.0.7-2
- irstlm 5.80.03-6
- moses-git 20121023-1 (which is mosesdecoder v1.0)

I am using phrase tables, reordering models and language models which are made 1 year ago (so maybe they are old but works ok with older versions).

This is complete stack from gdb

```
gdb /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver
    GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
    Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
    Reading symbols from /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
    (gdb) set args --serial -f /home/arch/models/ar-en-en-ar.v2.moses.ini
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver --serial -f /home/arch/models/ar-en-en-ar.v2.moses.ini
    warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
    warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
    Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
    Running single-threaded server
    Defined parameters (per moses.ini or switch):
        alternate-weight-setting: id=ar-en ignore-ff=LM1,LexicalReordering1 ignore-decoding-path=1 Distortion0= 0.3 WordPenalty0= -1 TranslationModel0= 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 LexicalReordering0= 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 LM0= 0.5 id=en-ar ignore-ff=LM0,LexicalReordering0 ignore-decoding-path=0 Distortion0= 0.3 WordPenalty0= -1 TranslationModel1= 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 LexicalReordering1= 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 LM1= 0.5 
        config: /home/arch/models/ar-en-en-ar.v2.moses.ini 
        distortion-limit: 12 
        feature: Distortion UnknownWordPenalty WordPenalty PhraseDictionaryBinary name=TranslationModel0 num-features=5 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/phrase-table/phrase-table input-factor=0 output-factor=0 table-limit=20 LexicalReordering num-features=6 name=LexicalReordering0 type=wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe-allff input-factor=0 output-factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/reordering-table/reordering-table.wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe.gz IRSTLM name=LM0 order=5 factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm PhraseDictionaryBinary name=TranslationModel1 num-features=5 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/phrase-table/phrase-table input-factor=0 output-factor=0 table-limit=20 LexicalReordering num-features=6 name=LexicalReordering1 type=wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe-allff input-factor=0 output-factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/reordering-model/reordering-table.wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe.gz IRSTLM name=LM1 order=5 factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm 
        input-factors: 0 
        mapping: 0 T 0 1 T 1 
        weight: Distortion0= 0 WordPenalty0= 0 TranslationModel0= 0 0 0 0 0 LexicalReordering0= 0 0 0 0 0 0 LM0= 0 TranslationModel1= 0 0 0 0 0 LexicalReordering1= 0 0 0 0 0 0 LM1= 0 
    /opt/moses/bin
    line=Distortion
    FeatureFunction: Distortion0 start: 0 end: 0
    line=UnknownWordPenalty
    FeatureFunction: UnknownWordPenalty0 start: 1 end: 1
    line=WordPenalty
    FeatureFunction: WordPenalty0 start: 2 end: 2
    line=PhraseDictionaryBinary name=TranslationModel0 num-features=5 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/phrase-table/phrase-table input-factor=0 output-factor=0 table-limit=20
    FeatureFunction: TranslationModel0 start: 3 end: 7
    line=LexicalReordering num-features=6 name=LexicalReordering0 type=wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe-allff input-factor=0 output-factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/reordering-table/reordering-table.wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe.gz
    FeatureFunction: LexicalReordering0 start: 8 end: 13
    Initializing LexicalReordering..
    line=IRSTLM name=LM0 order=5 factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    FeatureFunction: LM0 start: 14 end: 14
    line=PhraseDictionaryBinary name=TranslationModel1 num-features=5 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/phrase-table/phrase-table input-factor=0 output-factor=0 table-limit=20
    FeatureFunction: TranslationModel1 start: 15 end: 19
    line=LexicalReordering num-features=6 name=LexicalReordering1 type=wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe-allff input-factor=0 output-factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/reordering-model/reordering-table.wbe-msd-bidirectional-fe.gz
    FeatureFunction: LexicalReordering1 start: 20 end: 25
    Initializing LexicalReordering..
    line=IRSTLM name=LM1 order=5 factor=0 path=/home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    FeatureFunction: LM1 start: 26 end: 26
    Loading table into memory...done.
    In LanguageModelIRST::Load: nGramOrder = 5
    Language Model Type of /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm is 1
    Language Model Type is 1
    Qblmt
    loadbin()
    reading  256 centers
    reading  256 centers
    reading  256 centers
    reading  256 centers
    reading  256 centers
    lmtable::loadbin_dict()
    dict->size(): 1333355
    loadbin_level (level 1)
    mapping 1333355 1-grams
    tableOffs 17505786 tableGaps3578-grams
    done (level 1)
    loadbin_level (level 2)
    mapping 29430840 2-grams
    tableOffs 29508029 tableGaps445-grams
    done (level 2)
    loadbin_level (level 3)
    mapping 65275252 3-grams
    tableOffs 294387637 tableGaps4021-grams
    done (level 3)
    loadbin_level (level 4)
    mapping 112541864 4-grams
    tableOffs 881866953 tableGaps2249-grams
    done (level 4)
    loadbin_level (level 5)
    mapping 133661243 5-grams
    tableOffs 1894744753 tableGaps689-grams
    done (level 5)
    done
    OOV code is 1333354
    IRST: m_unknownId=1333354
    Loading table into memory...done.
    In LanguageModelIRST::Load: nGramOrder = 5
    Language Model Type of /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm is 1
    Language Model Type is 1
    blmt
    loadbin()
    lmtable::loadbin_dict()
    dict->size(): 55868
    loadbin_level (level 1)
    mapping 55868 1-grams
    tableOffs 848701 tableGaps829-grams
    done (level 1)
    loadbin_level (level 2)
    mapping 505197 2-grams
    tableOffs 1686721 tableGaps3265-grams
    done (level 2)
    loadbin_level (level 3)
    mapping 1008086 3-grams
    tableOffs 9264676 tableGaps3620-grams
    done (level 3)
    loadbin_level (level 4)
    mapping 1359605 4-grams
    tableOffs 24385966 tableGaps2478-grams
    done (level 4)
    loadbin_level (level 5)
    mapping 1571266 5-grams
    tableOffs 44780041 tableGaps2569-grams
    done (level 5)
    done
    OOV code is 55867
    IRST: m_unknownId=55867
    alternate weight setting ar-en
    alternate weight setting en-ar
    Listening on port 8080
    Input: <seg weight-setting="ar-en">ولادة الحكومة السورية المؤقتة بعد مصادقة الائتلاف</seg>
    Translating: ولادة الحكومة السورية المؤقتة بعد مصادقة الائتلاف 
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    Line 0: Collecting options took 0 seconds
    Line 0: Search took 0 seconds
    reset caches
    reset caches
    Output: ولادة الحكومة السورية المؤقتة after مصادقة الائتلاف 
    Input: <seg weight-setting="ar-en">ا ف ب رويترز الائتلاف الوطني السوري العربية المستقبل اختتم مؤتمر الائتلاف الوطني السوري المعارض اجتماعاته في اسطنبول بعد منتصف ليل أمس بإعلان حكومة مؤقتة برئاسة أحمد طعمة بعد تصويت الهيئة العامة للائتلاف</seg>
    Translating: ا ف ب رويترز الائتلاف الوطني السوري العربية المستقبل اختتم مؤتمر الائتلاف الوطني السوري المعارض اجتماعاته في اسطنبول بعد منتصف ليل أمس بإعلان حكومة مؤقتة برئاسة أحمد طعمة بعد تصويت الهيئة العامة للائتلاف 
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    Line 0: Collecting options took 22 seconds
    Line 0: Search took 2 seconds
    reset caches
    reset caches
    Output: a syrian العربية مؤتمر الائتلاف الائتلاف in the national gallery 's future ended reuters during national ليل أمس بإعلان حكومة مؤقتة برئاسة أحمد طعمة in istanbul after midnight after a الهيئة العامة للائتلاف 
    Input: <seg weight-setting="ar-en">على أسماء كل المرشحين في التشكيلة التي قدمها طعمة أول من أمس وعلمت المستقبل أن ثلاثة من المرشحين سقطوا في التصويت وهم عمار القربي المرشح لوزارة الداخلية وعبدالرحمن الحاج للتعليم ومحمد مقبل جران</seg>
    Translating: على أسماء كل المرشحين في التشكيلة التي قدمها طعمة أول من أمس وعلمت المستقبل أن ثلاثة من المرشحين سقطوا في التصويت وهم عمار القربي المرشح لوزارة الداخلية وعبدالرحمن الحاج للتعليم ومحمد مقبل جران 
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    Line 0: Collecting options took 0 seconds
    Line 0: Search took 3 seconds
    reset caches
    reset caches
    Output: على أسماء التشكيلة طعمة أول أمس وعلمت of all the candidates in the upcoming أن ثلاثة candidates سقطوا لوزارة الداخلية وعبدالرحمن haji للتعليم ومحمد candidate in the vote they ammar al-qirbi مقبل جران 
    Input: <seg weight-setting="ar-en">للصحة وأفادت مصادر الائتلاف أن طعمة سيعمل على ترشيح ثلاثة مرشحين جدد لها على أن يجري التصويت عليهم لاحقاً وتشكلت الحكومة التي نالت ثقة الائتلاف من اياد قدسي نائباً للرئيس اللواء عبدالعزيز الشلال</seg>
    Translating: للصحة وأفادت مصادر الائتلاف أن طعمة سيعمل على ترشيح ثلاثة مرشحين جدد لها على أن يجري التصويت عليهم لاحقاً وتشكلت الحكومة التي نالت ثقة الائتلاف من اياد قدسي نائباً للرئيس اللواء عبدالعزيز الشلال 
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    reading bin ttable
    size of OFF_T 8
    binary phrasefile loaded, default OFF_T: -1
    *** Error in `/opt/moses/bin/mosesserver': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000ec8d1470 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x72e5f)[0x7ffff5042e5f]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7862e)[0x7ffff504862e]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x79307)[0x7ffff5049307]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x4bd7f6]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x4c8d10]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x4c8506]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x46396e]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x48f009]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x47fe13]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x416652]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8(+0x4d20)[0x7ffff6f8dd20]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3(xmlrpc_dispatchCall+0x8c)[0x7ffff6b7d03c]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3(xmlrpc_registry_process_call2+0xc2)[0x7ffff6b7d172]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8(_ZNK8xmlrpc_c8registry11processCallERKSsPKNS_8callInfoEPSs+0x43)[0x7ffff6f8d903]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8(_ZN8xmlrpc_c16serverAbyss_impl11processCallERKSsP9_TSessionPSs+0x34)[0x7ffff7195f94]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8(+0x5036)[0x7ffff7196036]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3(xmlrpc_handleIfXmlrpcReq+0x5c8)[0x7ffff6d862e8]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3(+0xc86d)[0x7ffff697086d]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3(+0xcae8)[0x7ffff6970ae8]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3(ConnProcess+0xe)[0x7ffff696b6fe]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3(+0xcc21)[0x7ffff6970c21]
    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3(ServerRunOnce+0xac)[0x7ffff6971c3c]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x40be37]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7ffff4ff1bc5]
    /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver[0x410931]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-00670000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1847576                            /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver
    0086f000-00870000 r--p 0026f000 fe:02 1847576                            /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver
    00870000-00871000 rw-p 00270000 fe:02 1847576                            /opt/moses/bin/mosesserver
    00871000-00894000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    00894000-00895000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    00895000-ecc71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    7fff58000000-7fff58021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fff58021000-7fff5c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7fff5e29b000-7fff5ed19000 r--s 02ab4000 fe:02 1713184                    /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    7fff5ed19000-7fff6008d000 r--s 01741000 fe:02 1713184                    /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    7fff6008d000-7fff60efa000 r--s 008d5000 fe:02 1713184                    /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    7fff60efa000-7fff80cdb000 r--s 70ef8000 fe:02 1713173                    /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    7fff80cdb000-7fffbd2d0000 r--s 34903000 fe:02 1713173                    /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    7fffbd2d0000-7fffe0315000 r--s 118bf000 fe:02 1713173                    /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    7fffe0315000-7fffeffb1000 r--s 01c24000 fe:02 1713173                    /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    7fffeffb1000-7ffff351b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff3d22000-7ffff445d000 r--s 0019b000 fe:02 1713184                    /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    7ffff445d000-7ffff4fd0000 r--s 010b1000 fe:02 1713173                    /home/arch/models/ar-en/language-model/en.qblm.mm
    7ffff4fd0000-7ffff5172000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051865                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
    7ffff5172000-7ffff5371000 ---p 001a2000 fe:02 1051865                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
    7ffff5371000-7ffff5375000 r--p 001a1000 fe:02 1051865                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
    7ffff5375000-7ffff5377000 rw-p 001a5000 fe:02 1051865                    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
    7ffff5377000-7ffff537b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff537b000-7ffff5390000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1067124                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    7ffff5390000-7ffff5590000 ---p 00015000 fe:02 1067124                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    7ffff5590000-7ffff5591000 rw-p 00015000 fe:02 1067124                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
    7ffff5591000-7ffff5693000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051863                    /usr/lib/libm-2.18.so
    7ffff5693000-7ffff5892000 ---p 00102000 fe:02 1051863                    /usr/lib/libm-2.18.so
    7ffff5892000-7ffff5893000 r--p 00101000 fe:02 1051863                    /usr/lib/libm-2.18.so
    7ffff5893000-7ffff5894000 rw-p 00102000 fe:02 1051863                    /usr/lib/libm-2.18.so
    7ffff5894000-7ffff597a000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1067118                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    7ffff597a000-7ffff5b79000 ---p 000e6000 fe:02 1067118                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    7ffff5b79000-7ffff5b81000 r--p 000e5000 fe:02 1067118                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    7ffff5b81000-7ffff5b83000 rw-p 000ed000 fe:02 1067118                    /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
    7ffff5b83000-7ffff5b98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff5b98000-7ffff5bb0000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051829                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
    7ffff5bb0000-7ffff5db0000 ---p 00018000 fe:02 1051829                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
    7ffff5db0000-7ffff5db1000 r--p 00018000 fe:02 1051829                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
    7ffff5db1000-7ffff5db2000 rw-p 00019000 fe:02 1051829                    /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
    7ffff5db2000-7ffff5db6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff5db6000-7ffff5dbb000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1079027                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_util.so.3.36
    7ffff5dbb000-7ffff5fba000 ---p 00005000 fe:02 1079027                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_util.so.3.36
    7ffff5fba000-7ffff5fbb000 r--p 00004000 fe:02 1079027                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_util.so.3.36
    7ffff5fbb000-7ffff5fbc000 rw-p 00005000 fe:02 1079027                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_util.so.3.36
    7ffff5fbc000-7ffff5fd1000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1054911                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
    7ffff5fd1000-7ffff61d0000 ---p 00015000 fe:02 1054911                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
    7ffff61d0000-7ffff61d1000 r--p 00014000 fe:02 1054911                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
    7ffff61d1000-7ffff61d2000 rw-p 00015000 fe:02 1054911                    /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
    7ffff61d2000-7ffff632f000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1078648                    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1
    7ffff632f000-7ffff652e000 ---p 0015d000 fe:02 1078648                    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1
    7ffff652e000-7ffff6536000 r--p 0015c000 fe:02 1078648                    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1
    7ffff6536000-7ffff6538000 rw-p 00164000 fe:02 1078648                    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.1
    7ffff6538000-7ffff653a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff653a000-7ffff654e000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1078991                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc.so.3.36
    7ffff654e000-7ffff674e000 ---p 00014000 fe:02 1078991                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc.so.3.36
    7ffff674e000-7ffff674f000 r--p 00014000 fe:02 1078991                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc.so.3.36
    7ffff674f000-7ffff6750000 rw-p 00015000 fe:02 1078991                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc.so.3.36
    7ffff6750000-7ffff6763000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1078988                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc++.so.8.36
    7ffff6763000-7ffff6962000 ---p 00013000 fe:02 1078988                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc++.so.8.36
    7ffff6962000-7ffff6963000 r--p 00012000 fe:02 1078988                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc++.so.8.36
    7ffff6963000-7ffff6964000 rw-p 00013000 fe:02 1078988                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc++.so.8.36
    7ffff6964000-7ffff697a000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1078994                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff697a000-7ffff6b79000 ---p 00016000 fe:02 1078994                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6b79000-7ffff6b7a000 r--p 00015000 fe:02 1078994                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6b7a000-7ffff6b7b000 rw-p 00016000 fe:02 1078994                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6b7b000-7ffff6b80000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1079012                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3.36
    7ffff6b80000-7ffff6d80000 ---p 00005000 fe:02 1079012                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3.36
    7ffff6d80000-7ffff6d81000 r--p 00005000 fe:02 1079012                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3.36
    7ffff6d81000-7ffff6d82000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 1079012                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3.36
    7ffff6d82000-7ffff6d88000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1079018                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6d88000-7ffff6f87000 ---p 00006000 fe:02 1079018                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6f87000-7ffff6f88000 r--p 00005000 fe:02 1079018                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6f88000-7ffff6f89000 rw-p 00006000 fe:02 1079018                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3.36
    7ffff6f89000-7ffff6f90000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1079009                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8.36
    7ffff6f90000-7ffff718f000 ---p 00007000 fe:02 1079009                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8.36
    7ffff718f000-7ffff7190000 r--p 00006000 fe:02 1079009                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8.36
    7ffff7190000-7ffff7191000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 1079009                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8.36
    7ffff7191000-7ffff7198000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1079015                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8.36
    7ffff7198000-7ffff7397000 ---p 00007000 fe:02 1079015                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8.36
    7ffff7397000-7ffff7398000 r--p 00006000 fe:02 1079015                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8.36
    7ffff7398000-7ffff7399000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 1079015                    /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8.36
    7ffff7399000-7ffff739d000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051838                    /usr/lib/libSegFault.so
    7ffff739d000-7ffff759c000 ---p 00004000 fe:02 1051838                    /usr/lib/libSegFault.so
    7ffff759c000-7ffff759d000 r--p 00003000 fe:02 1051838                    /usr/lib/libSegFault.so
    7ffff759d000-7ffff759e000 rw-p 00004000 fe:02 1051838                    /usr/lib/libSegFault.so
    7ffff759e000-7ffff75a1000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051899                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
    7ffff75a1000-7ffff77a0000 ---p 00003000 fe:02 1051899                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
    7ffff77a0000-7ffff77a1000 r--p 00002000 fe:02 1051899                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
    7ffff77a1000-7ffff77a2000 rw-p 00003000 fe:02 1051899                    /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
    7ffff77a2000-7ffff77a9000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051898                    /usr/lib/librt-2.18.so
    7ffff77a9000-7ffff79a8000 ---p 00007000 fe:02 1051898                    /usr/lib/librt-2.18.so
    7ffff79a8000-7ffff79a9000 r--p 00006000 fe:02 1051898                    /usr/lib/librt-2.18.so
    7ffff79a9000-7ffff79aa000 rw-p 00007000 fe:02 1051898                    /usr/lib/librt-2.18.so
    7ffff79aa000-7ffff79b9000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1054839                    /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0.6
    7ffff79b9000-7ffff7bb8000 ---p 0000f000 fe:02 1054839                    /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0.6
    7ffff7bb8000-7ffff7bba000 rw-p 0000e000 fe:02 1054839                    /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0.6
    7ffff7bba000-7ffff7bdb000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1057508                    /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
    7ffff7bdb000-7ffff7ddb000 ---p 00021000 fe:02 1057508                    /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
    7ffff7ddb000-7ffff7ddc000 r--p 00021000 fe:02 1057508                    /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
    7ffff7ddc000-7ffff7ddd000 rw-p 00022000 fe:02 1057508                    /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.5
    7ffff7ddd000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 fe:02 1051847                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
    7ffff7f16000-7ffff7fe3000 r--s 000cf000 fe:02 1713184                    /home/arch/models/en-ar/language-model/ar.lm.d1.blm.mm
    7ffff7fe3000-7ffff7ff0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff7ff7000-7ffff7ffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
    7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 0001f000 fe:02 1051847                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
    7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00020000 fe:02 1051847                    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
    7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7ffffffcc000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
    ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

    Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
    0x00007ffff50053d9 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x00007ffff50053d9 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00007ffff50067d8 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00007ffff5042e64 in __libc_message () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #3  0x00007ffff504862e in malloc_printerr () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #4  0x00007ffff5049307 in _int_free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #5  0x00000000004bd7f6 in ?? ()
    #6  0x00000000004c8d10 in ?? ()
    #7  0x00000000004c8506 in ?? ()
    #8  0x000000000046396e in ?? ()
    #9  0x000000000048f009 in ?? ()
    #10 0x000000000047fe13 in ?? ()
    #11 0x0000000000416652 in ?? ()
    #12 0x00007ffff6f8dd20 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8
    #13 0x00007ffff6b7d03c in xmlrpc_dispatchCall () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3
    #14 0x00007ffff6b7d172 in xmlrpc_registry_process_call2 () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server.so.3
    #15 0x00007ffff6f8d903 in xmlrpc_c::registry::processCall(std::string const&, xmlrpc_c::callInfo const*, std::string*) const () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server++.so.8
    #16 0x00007ffff7195f94 in xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss_impl::processCall(std::string const&, _TSession*, std::string*) () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8
    #17 0x00007ffff7196036 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss++.so.8
    #18 0x00007ffff6d862e8 in xmlrpc_handleIfXmlrpcReq () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_server_abyss.so.3
    ---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    #19 0x00007ffff697086d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    #20 0x00007ffff6970ae8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    #21 0x00007ffff696b6fe in ConnProcess () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    #22 0x00007ffff6970c21 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    #23 0x00007ffff6971c3c in ServerRunOnce () from /usr/lib/libxmlrpc_abyss.so.3
    #24 0x000000000040be37 in ?? ()
    #25 0x00007ffff4ff1bc5 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
    #26 0x0000000000410931 in ?? ()
    (gdb) quit
```

Can someone help me with this error. I suspect in two things: old data models and xmlrpc-c libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to GCC bug. Downgrade to GCC 4.6.3, and then recompile it. Check this discussion https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/issues/51